# PostGIS convert meters to degree using epsg 5186

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a few questions about geometry and geography in PostGIS.

I am currently using PostGIS and Postgresql.

Most of my spatial data is from Korea which is basically latitude and longitude.

For testing, I have created two tables with the same latitude and longitude data but different data types, one for geography with SRID 4326 and the other for geometry with SRID 5186.

```
create table geometry_stores
(
    id       serial primary key,
    location geometry(POINT, 5186) not null
);

create table geography_stores
(
    id       serial primary key,
    location geography(POINT, 4326) not null
);
```

You can find more details of EPSG 5186 on this link https://epsg.io/5186

Here is a list of question I have got:

1. PostGIS has this method

   `ST_DWithin(geometry g1, geometry g2, double precision distance_of_srid);`

   is `distance_of_srid` a unit of EPSG? Is there any way I can convert meters (e.g. 1km) to `distance_of_srid` with EPSG 5186?
2. I understand that geography calculation measures the distances between points as true paths over a sphere while geometry calculation measures the distances between points as true paths over a Cartesian plane. Then if I give exactly the same distance to the following queries, they are supposed to yield different results or same results? because my understanding is that geometry with SRID 5186 is already projected with distortion of earth, then they should yield the same results?

   ```
   select *
   from geography_stores
   where st_dwithin(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 4326), same_distance_meter)
   ```

   ```
   select *
   from geometry_stores
   where st_dwithin(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186), same_distance_degree)
   ```
3. When I calculate distance on the geometry table with the following query, it gives me a degree, not meters. Is there any way I can convert this degree to meters with consideration of distortion of the earth?

   ```
   select st_distance(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186))
   from geometry_stores
   where id = 1;
   ```

   I have tried with this query but got some error of  `Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in  geography. Where: SQL function "st_distancesphere" during inlining`

   ```
   select st_distancesphere(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186))
   from geometry_stores
   where id = 1;
   ```

I have read documents at the PostGIS website and some questions in StackOverflow but still got those three questions. Thank you guys for your help.

---

### ------------------------------- UPDATED -----------------------------------------

1. The column for my spatial data is geometry(POINT, 5186) so the table definition would be as following. Note that it is not geometry(POINT, 4326) not to convert it to geometry(POINT, 5186) on calculation. Should I store my data in geometry(POINT, 4326) and convert it on calculation?

```
create table geometry_stores
(
    id       serial primary key,
    location geometry(POINT, 5186) not null
);
```

2. I executed following query and got results as follows:

```
select st_distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(126.808183, 37.463557), 4326)::geography,
                   st_setsrid(st_makepoint(126.970769, 37.555479), 4326)::geography);


st_distance
--------------
17627.3138509
```

```
select st_distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(126.808183, 37.463557), 5186)::geometry,
                   st_setsrid(st_makepoint(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186)::geometry)

st_distance
--------------
0.186772218169622
```

It seems that the second's query gives me degree while the first one gives me meters. Am I doing something wrong in my query, please?

3. For st_within, I populated 3M data in geometry_stores table and the spatial data spread over at least 10km. I executed the following query.

```
select *
from users
where st_dwithin(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186), 0.001)
```

This query gives me 158 rows and geometry viewer displays as per picture below.

[image]

Let's execute the same query with distance 1 not 0.0001

```
select *
from users
where st_dwithin(location, st_setsrid(st_point(126.970769, 37.555479), 5186), 1)
```

This query gives me 32792923 rows which is all data in the table.

Considering that the spatial data spread over at least 10km, it seems that the st_within query calculates the distance between two geometries with a unit (degeree) of EPSG5186 not meters. Then, I'd like to know if I can convert meters to the unit (degree) of EPSG5186 because I'd like to query with meters, not degree which I don't know how far a unit (degree) of EPSG5186 is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is distance_of_srid a unit of EPSG?

Yes. Distances using `geometry` type geometries are calculated using the unit of measurement from the corresponding Spatial Reference System.

> Is there any way I can convert meters (e.g. 1km) to distance_of_srid with EPSG 5186?

According to the [`documentation`](https://epsg.io/5186), the unit of `EPSG:5186` is already metres, so you don't have to convert anything. Bur also keep in mind that distances using `geography` type geometries are also calculated using `metres`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(
   'SRID=4326;POINT(127.49 36.65)'::geometry,
   'SRID=4326;POINT(128.06 36.43)'::geometry) AS geometry_distance,
  ST_Distance(
   'SRID=4326;POINT(127.49 36.65)'::geography,
   'SRID=4326;POINT(128.06 36.43)'::geography) AS geography_distance
   ;
 geometry_distance | geography_distance 
-------------------+--------------------
 0.610982814815612 |     56578.57823391
(1 Zeile)
```

> Then if I give exactly the same distance to the following queries, they are supposed to yield different results or same results? because my understanding is that geometry with SRID 5186 is already projected with distortion of earth, then they should yield the same results?

The results will differ. They might have the same unit of measurement, but they aren't projected on the same surface. The following example transforms the coordinates from `4326` to `5186` and calculates the distance:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(
   'SRID=4326;POINT(127.49 36.65)'::geography,
   'SRID=4326;POINT(128.06 36.43)'::geography),
  ST_Distance(
   ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(127.49 36.65)'::geometry,5186),
   ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(128.06 36.43)'::geometry,5186));

  st_distance   |   st_distance    
----------------+------------------
 56578.57823391 | 56582.0899018353
(1 Zeile)
```

> When I calculate distance on the geometry table with the following query, it gives me a degree, not meters. Is there any way I can convert this degree to meters with consideration of distortion of the earth?

Isn't the data type `geography` what you're looking for? As the documentation says:

*Regardless which spatial reference system you use, the units returned by the measurement (ST_Distance, ST_Length, ST_Perimeter, ST_Area) and for input of ST_DWithin are in meters.*

Just for fun, the following query calculates the distance between two points explicitly defining the `4326` spheroid, using [`ST_DistanceSpheroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html), and casting the coordinates from `geometry` to `geography`, which basically does the same:

```
SELECT 
  ST_DistanceSpheroid(  
   'POINT(127.49 36.65)',
   'POINT(128.06 36.43)',
   'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'),
  ST_Distance( 
   'SRID=4326;POINT(127.49 36.65)'::geography,
   'SRID=4326;POINT(128.06 36.43)'::geography);

 st_distancespheroid |  st_distance   
---------------------+----------------
    56578.5782339123 | 56578.57823391
```

Regarding when to use `geometry` or `geography` the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry) says:

*"The type you choose should be conditioned on the expected working area of the application you are building. Will your data span the globe or a large continental area, or is it local to a state, county or municipality?"*

Things to consider:

- use case covers small area: stick to `geometry` and use a SRS that better suits your area.
- use case covers large areas (countries/continents): use `geography` - although it might be a bit slower.
- Do the functions you wanna use support `geography`? Most PostGIS functions **do not** support it! Check this [`matrix`](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix) for more details. If the functions you wanna use do not support `geography`, you have no other choice but to use `geometry` ;-) Since your use case mostly covers Korea, I see no problem in using `EPSG 5186`.

**EDIT**: Regarding the question Update.

You cannot simply change the `SRID` of geometries to get it transformed into another reference system! What you've done was to get a `WGS84` coordinate pairs and simply exchange its `SRID`, which is not the way it works. You have to **always** use [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) for that. Take a look what the coordinates look like after you apply it:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(126.808183 37.463557)'::geometry,5186));

                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(183030.248454493 540476.713582621)
(1 Zeile)
```

It means that `POINT(183030.248454493 540476.713582621)` and `POINT(126.808183 37.463557)` are the same coordinate pairs, but in different reference systems. The following query will make it clear that both `geography` and `5186` return results in metres:

```
SELECT 
  --Transforming from 4326 to 5186 and calculating the distance
  ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(126.808183 37.463557)'::geometry, 5186),
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(126.970769 37.555479)'::geometry, 5186)),
  -- Distance using geography
  ST_Distance(
    'SRID=4326;POINT(126.808183 37.463557)'::geography,
    'SRID=4326;POINT(126.970769 37.555479)'::geography);

   st_distance    |  st_distance  
------------------+---------------
 17627.3383377316 | 17627.3138509
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed response. I much appreciate it. I understand that you can cast geometry type to geography but what I wanted to do was basically to use geometry type with SRID 5186 not geography type because PostGIS doc says geometry with specific EPSG would be much faster than geography. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @kisungTae queries with `geometry` are indeed faster than with `geography`, but it is less accurate ;-) It is a fair trade off and the answer you're looking for basically depends on your use case. The rule of thumb is: If your area small, use `geometry`. If it is global/continental, stick to `geography`.

Comment: @kisungTae how large is your dataset?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. "if your area small, use geometry", as I mentioned in the question, most of my data is from one country, South Korea, and that's why I wanted to use geometry with SRID 5186, and dataset would 5-10M but not really sure it might be more than that.

Comment: So, basically I wanted to use st_within and st_distance with geometry with EPSG 5186, but the results of those functions are unit of EPSG 5186 and I wanted to know if there is any way to convert the unit to meters that I can easily read and understand. Bare with me having no idea of how the calculation would be done and if possible please enlighten me.

Comment: for st_within, I need to put unit of EPSG 5186 for distance not meters, but I don't know how to convert 1km to unit of EPSG 5186. So I wanted to know if there is any way to convert 1km to unit of EPSG5186

Comment: for st_distance, I need to display km between two geometry points but st_distance(geometry, geometry) gives me a unit of EPSG5186, not meters so I'd like to know if I can convert this unit to meters.

Comment: I mentioned 1km but it is not static and I just want to know kind of formula or something to convert meters to a unit of EPSG5186

Comment: good morning, @kisungTae :-). The documentation of `EPSG:5186` says it **already uses metre as unit**, so I don't really know to which unit you want to convert. I'm not familiar with this projection, but if I understood it correctly, you can simply provide distances in metres in functions like `ST_DWithin` and you will get the result of `ST_Distance` also in metres. In my second query we can see that the results are almost identical to the `geography` results, which also uses metres.

Comment: Good morning and hope you had a tight sleep. I have just updated my answer so please review the question if possible and suggest some ideas if any, please.